# SVG stroke-dashadjust polyfill. Trying to get SVG dotted stroke to align dots at the ends

Tags: svg, stroke, illustrator-scripting, javascript

[W3C SVG Strokes](https://www.w3.org/TR/svg-strokes/) introduces [`stroke-dashadjust`](https://www.w3.org/TR/svg-strokes/#StrokeDashadjustProperty) but no browser implements it yet.

Adobe Illustrator's stroke panel has a button for this feature – its tooltip reads **Aligns dashes to corners and path ends, adjusting lengths to fit**

When you set it and export SVG what it does is take your initial settings, say `0pt dash, 5pt gap` and tweak them, outputting a `stroke-dasharray` attribute like `0,4.9121`.

I wanted to use this for connecting text with plots on charts, before support for this new attribute arrives in browsers. My use case only involved straight lines (so not worrying about paths with corners yet): connecting label text with bars in a bar chart.

More details:
[Proposals/Stroke dash adjustment - SVG](https://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/WG/wiki/Proposals/Stroke_dash_adjustment)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wanted to ask but then I figured it out:

```js
// Select your lines and convert to array
const linesArray = [...document.querySelector('svg path.straight-line')];

linesArray.forEach(line => {
  const len = line.getTotalLength();
  // Compute stroke-dasharray attribute values
  const dasharray = (len, gap) => {
    // How many segments?
    return (len%gap < gap/2)
      // Is it closer to go lower?
      ? +(len / Math.floor(len/gap)).toFixed(4) - 0.01
      // or higher?
      : +(len / Math.ceil(len/gap)).toFixed(4) - 0.01;
  };
  line.setAttribute('stroke-dasharray', `0,${dasharray(len, 5)}`);
});
```

Uses [SVGPathElement.getTotalLength](http://devdocs.io/dom/svgpathelement/gettotallength) which has sketchy support itself... It can be replaced with parsing the path's `d` attribute.